# after unceck option = exit Tor error

Tags: error

[after unceck this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXcx.jpg)

[i got error on close Tor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYw8t.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of the text inside the screenshot?